# how to php code for electricity calculation?

Tags: php

The following array contains the unit usage of electricity of a particular household for a period of one year.

```
$usage = [
 'Jan' => '156',
 'Feb' => '125',
 'Mar' => '112',
 'Apr' => '175',
 'May' => '210',
 'Jun' => '96',
 'Jul' => '123',
 'Aug' => '135',
 'Sep' => '184',
 'Oct' => '159',
 'Nov' => '140',
 'Dec' => '194',
];
```

Consider that the per unit charge up to 150 units is 5 Rs. If the monthly usage goes above the threshold of 150 units, the extra units will be charged at 7 Rs per unit. For example, Total charge for 160 units will be (150*5)+(10*7) = 820 Rs.

Write a function to calculate the total bill amount for a year if the user is billed monthly and annually. When billed annually, the total number of units available for the user in a lower price (5 Rs) will be 150 * 12 = 1800 units, beyond which the units will be charged at the rate
 of 7 RS per unit.

**EDIT** (to add code from OP's comments below):

```
<?php if($units < 150){ 
    $bill = 150 * 5; 
    $remaining_units= $units -150; 
    if($remaining_units > 150 ){ 
        $remaining_units= $remaining_units -150; 
        $bill = $bill + (150* 7); 
        if($remaining_units > 150 || $remaining_units < 150){  
            $remaining_units= $remaining_units -100; 
            $bill = $bill + (150* 7);
```

Iam noob .trying to solve random questions

Comment: It looks like homework task. Can you share, what have you tried?

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: what have you tried so far? Please post your solution.

Comment: <?php
     if($units < 150){
$bill = 150 * 5;
$remaining_units= $units  -150;

if($remaining_units > 150 ){
    $remaining_units= $remaining_units  -150;
    $bill = $bill +  (150* 7);
    if($remaining_units > 150 || $remaining_units < 150){
         $remaining_units= $remaining_units  -100;
        $bill = $bill +  (150* 7);   Iam noob .trying to solve random questions

Answer (score 1):

```
$monthly = 0;
foreach($usage as $month => $unit) {
    $monthly += $unit > 150 ? (150*5) + (($unit-150)*7) : $unit*5;
}
$annually = array_sum($usage) > 1800 ? (1800*5) + ((array_sum($usage) - 1800)*7) : array_sum($usage)*5;
```

Monthly: If units are above 150, higher rate of 7 is to be charged for extra units. This calculation is completed in line 3.

Annually: Similarly, if units are above 1800, higher rate of 7 is charged for extra units. Refer line 5.

Comment: Code-only answers are not very useful.  Consider adding some comments, some hints, some direction.  OP admits is a "noop", so offer some helpful advice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what your code must be. The below getCostPerMonth calculates the bill amount of each month. This function takes number of units as argument and returns the cost.

$usage contains the units of electricity spent per month.

```
<?php
$usage = [
  'Jan' => '156',
  'Feb' => '125',
  'Mar' => '112',
  'Apr' => '175',
  'May' => '210',
  'Jun' => '96',
  'Jul' => '123',
  'Aug' => '135',
  'Sep' => '184',
  'Oct' => '159',
  'Nov' => '140',
  'Dec' => '194',
];
$bill = 0;

function getCostPerMonth($units) {
  if ($units <= 150) {
    return $units * 5; // For the first 150 units cost is 5 per unit.
  }
  else {
    // For the first 150 units cost is 5 per unit plus rest units at 7 per unit.
    return (150 * 5) + ($units - 150) * 7;
  }
}

foreach ($usage as $key => $value) {
  $bill += getCostPerMonth($value);
}
echo $bill;
?>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not very useful.  Consider adding some comments, some hints, some direction.  OP admits is a "noop", so offer some helpful advice.

Comment: added more comments / descriptions.